# I need a tag generated, please

Tags: support

Microsoft [claims](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Community.htm)* they monitor the **WindowsIoT** tag here.  No such tag exists, however.  The alternative is their "forum," which is actually the arduino.cc community, and the maker/homebrew folks have no inside knowledge of WindowsIoT internals.

I've got two questions I'd like Microsoft to answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229549/networking-on-galileo-gen2-whats-the-mac-address) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229150/intel-galileo-gen2-serial-port-names-in-windows-iot).  Could somebody please tag them for me?

*See the last entry in the "Forums" column.

Comment: I've edited your post. Referring to Microsoft with the $ sign incorporated is unimaginative, unprofessional, and so 1990's.

Comment: If you're shatting on M$ then why develop on their platform?  Sounds idiotic.

Answer (score 3):

There's already a [windows-10-iot-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-iot-core) tag on Stack Overflow. Microsoft should probably link to that on their support page instead, since it appears to be what you need.

Comment: It might be if I were using Windows 10 IoT.  I'm using Windows 8.1 IoT, however.

Comment: @Ron Then there should be a specific tag for that so they're not confused. Considering the tag that MS specified on their support page doesn't exist, I doubt they're monitoring it anyway.

Comment: @Ron Would `windows-8-iot` be appropriate for your questions, or `windows-8-iot-core`? (I don't know anything about any of this.)

Comment: Do you really think I can get Mohammed to come to the mountain?  Some poor intern is probably clicking on that link once an hour and questioning his life choices.  I just wanted to brighten his day.

Comment: @Ron You can [edit that page on GitHub](https://github.com/ms-iot/content/blob/develop/en-US/Community.md) if you want them to use the right tags. For our part, we should create the right tags.

Comment: You're assuming they go back to github instead of using a robot or browser shortcut.  I could argue that "windows-10-iot-core" is too specific.

Comment: @Ron The page was updated 8 days ago. Someone is watching GitHub. Instead of arguing about "windows-10-iot-core", why don't you just tell me the correct tag so we can get this done?

Comment: I wasn't trying to start an argument.  I just asked for a WindowsIoT tag.  And, why does the editor keep stripping my "@Bill" out?

Comment: @Ron The author of a post will always be notified of comments, so there's no need to address them. Use that for other commenters.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how tag synonyms work, and I don't think this is normally what they're used for, but would that solve this problem? I don't think "Get Microsoft to Change" is a very practical solution.

Comment: @WilliamNelson If they're using Stack Overflow as a support channel, "Get Microsoft to change" is exactly the right solution.